# VBA How to add cell values without looping

Tags: vba, excel

I have read about `Application.WorksheetFunction.Sum` but I was wondering if there is a specific method or property of the Range-object that does the job. I have looked into Range's members but I didn't find anything.

Is there a way to add without the use of a worksheet function? And without having to loop through each cell. Something like:

```
Sub test()
    Range("A1") = 1
    Range("A2") = 0
    Range("A3") = 2
    Range("A4") = Range("A1:A3").Add
    MsgBox Range("A4")
End Sub
```

With output 3.

Comment: is `Range("A4") = Application.WorksheetFunction.Sum(Range("A1:A3"))` so inconvinient ? why not use it if it's already tailored for you from Microsoft ?

Comment: I was just wondering if there is something more simple than the obvious that I already know. Thanks for your time though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

go on then, a 4th way :o)

```
evaluate(join(application.transpose(range("a1:a5").Value),"+"))
```

Comment: Not bad, not at all :D

Comment: Btw, I am not sure whether you really need the `transpose`. Something like this should work as well : `?evaluate(join(array(3,44,5),"+"))`

Comment: You need the transpose from the range, but not off an array defined as such.  You could just say `evaluate("3+44+5")` though if not using a range, seems no point :)

Comment: Actually, it is interesting that  if you need to sum values on the same row, you should use twice `Application.Transpose`. Like this: `?evaluate(join(application.transpose(application.transpose(Range("G2:I2").Value)),"+"))`

Comment: There's also the log of the factorial method to :) `=EXP(LN(FACT(A1:A3)))`

Comment: Thank you very much, both of you. I was studying your solutions to understand them.

Answer (score 2):

In general, there is a third way, which you did not mention:

`Application.Sum`

It  is a bit different than `WorksheetFunction.Sum`, in the fact that it is a bit more discrete - it does not throw errors with a MsgBox, even when it should.
Something like this will have only 2 errors thrown with `MsgBox` and you will get 2 errors in the immediate window:

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub WaysOfSumming()

    'This is Div/0 Error:
    Range("A1").Formula = "=5/0"

    Debug.Print Excel.WorksheetFunction.Sum(Range("A1"), 3, 5)
    Debug.Print Application.Sum(Range("A1"), 3, 5)

    Debug.Print Excel.WorksheetFunction.Sum(Range("A1"), 3, 5)
    Debug.Print Application.Sum(Range("A1"), 3, 5)

End Sub
```